# A question about the reward calculation in the Hindsight Experience Replay algorithm

Tags: reward-functions, off-policy-methods, hindsight-experience-replay, sparse-rewards

I' m try to implement the HER algorithm from scratch in order to use it in the [PandaReach-v3](https://panda-gym.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/advanced_rendering.html) environment.
I already developed the same algorithm for the bitflip environment and it works as expected.
So, what's now the problem?
The problem is the calculation of the new reward $r'$ given an additional *goal* as stated in the red box in the following picture:

[image]

The problem is, that while in the bitflip environment I just created a trivial function, that basically calculates the difference between the *state* $s_{t}$ and the *goal* $g'$, in the case of a more complex problem like the PandaReach I don't kwon how to proceed, since I cannot figure out, how the function for the calculation of the new reward given a  new goal should look like.

Basically I came up with the following two ideas:

1. I could implement a function, which calculates the 3D distance between the *state* and the *goal*. The function could output a *one*, if the calculated distance is below a small $\epsilon$ or *zero* otherwise;
2. I could use the already implemented *step* method (from the environment), which delivers in one step the new calculated reward. So no effort from my side. But here the problem is that I need to pass an action to the *step* method in order to generate a new *state* and calculate the *new reward*. And, for a new action, I need a policy. Since HER is a off policy algorithm I have a behavioural policy $\pi_{b}$ and nothing else. So my concern is whether I can/should/may use the same behavioural policy to sample an action to feed into the *step* method and get the *new reward*.

In other words: how do you calculate the new reward $r'$ in the HER algorithm?

Many thanks

Comment: HER typically assumes you have access to a reward function that can evaluate whether a certain state achieves the goal or not. If you can implement 1. then that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I can answer my own question.
After figuring it out, what the HER algorithm really needs, I found out, that the right answer is 1: you need a reward function for calculating the new reward and the new *done* flag.

In case you are at the first tries and you are trying to implement it using the panda-gym environment, this is what I did:

Inside the Panda environment there is a `compute_reward` function, which can be used to calculate the reward. Just pass the *actual state* and the *new goal* to that function.

In code:

```
import gymnasium as gyms import panda_gym

... 
env = gyms.make('PandaReach-v3')

...

# The compute_reward functions need an 'info' dictionary as third argument.
# Just pass an empty dictionary there.
# 'next_state' should replace with the variable you need. Since in my case
# I want to calculate the difference between 3 spatial coordinates, so I'm going to take 'next_state' and 'new_goal'. Both are 3D spatial coordinates 
new_reward = env.unwrapped.compute_reward(next_state, new_goal, {})
# Or in case you are not using any wrapper new_reward = 
env.computer_reward(next_state, new_goal, {})
```